# Why is my path moving in the opposite direction of the heuristic functions in A Star Algorithm?

Tags: python, path-finding

### Background

I want to implement an A-Star Algorithm with a GUI for user input to set the start and end node, and draw obstacles. However, I have spent a great deal of time pondering why the Algorithm isn't working.

### Issue

The path goes in the opposite direction of the end node and to the corner of the matrix. For example, if start: 2,2 and end: 8,8 the path will map to the origin: 0,0 and vice versa.

### Troubleshooting

I have already checked all the areas that I could possibly think is going wrong and even referring to source code from a medium article: [A-Star Algorithm by Nicholas Swift](https://medium.com/@nicholas.w.swift/easy-a-star-pathfinding-7e6689c7f7b2)

- Euclidean distance is not negative
- Adjacent nodes are not out of bounds
- Other smaller troubleshoot

The obstacles on the graph have not yet been implemented because I was trying to get the path to map correctly before adding additional complexity to the motivating problem.

I simply cannot see where I am going wrong. I come from a Java background so there could be some basic Python syntax that is escaping me and making everything break. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Source code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,x,y,nodeType):
        self.xPos = int(x)
        self.yPos = int(y)
        self.nodeType = str(nodeType)

        self.h = 0
        self.g = 0
        self.f = 0
    
    def __eq__(self,node):
        if((self.xPos == node.xPos) and (self.yPos == node.yPos)):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "(" + str(self.xPos) + "," + str(self.yPos) + "," + self.nodeType + ")"




class Graph:
    def __init__(self,size,startX,startY,endX,endY):
        self.graph = [[Node(x,y,"open") for y in range(size)] for x in range(size)]
        self.graph[startX][startY].nodeType = "start"
        self.graph[endX][endY].nodeType = "end"
        self.startNode = self.graph[startX][startY]
        self.endNode = self.graph[endX][endY]
    
    def displayGraph(self):
        for x in range(len(self.graph)):
            for y in range(len(self.graph[x])):
                print(self.graph[x][y],end=" ")
            print("")

    def getAdj(self,node):
        adjNodes = []
        x = int(node.xPos)
        y = int(node.yPos)
        if(self.inRange(x,y+1)):
            adjNodes.append(self.graph[x][y+1])
        if(self.inRange(x+1,y+1)):
            adjNodes.append(self.graph[x+1][y+1])
        if(self.inRange(x+1,y)):
            adjNodes.append(self.graph[x+1][y])
        if(self.inRange(x+1,y-1)):
            adjNodes.append(self.graph[x+1][y-1])
        if(self.inRange(x,y-1)):
            adjNodes.append(self.graph[x][y-1])
        if(self.inRange(x-1,y-1)):
            adjNodes.append(self.graph[x-1][y-1])
        if(self.inRange(x-1,y)):
            adjNodes.append(self.graph[x-1][y])
        if(self.inRange(x-1,y+1)):
            adjNodes.append(self.graph[x-1][y+1])

        for node in adjNodes:
            print(node,end=" ")
        print("")

        return adjNodes

    
    def inRange(self,x,y):
        if(x > -1 and x < len(self.graph) and y > - 1 and y < len(self.graph[0])):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
    def findShortestPath(self):
        openList = []
        closedList = []

        openList.append(self.startNode)
        count = 0

        while(len(openList) > 0):

            minNode = openList[0]
            minIndex = 0
            for i in range(len(openList)):
                if(minNode.f < openList[i].f):
                    minNode = openList[i]
                    minIndex = i
            
            openList.pop(minIndex)
            closedList.append(minNode)

            if(minNode == self.endNode):

                """
                Taken from article
                path = []
                current = minNode
                while current is not None:
                    path.append(current.position)
                    current = current.parent
                return path[::-1] # Return reversed path
                """
                return closedList


            adjNodes = self.getAdj(minNode)

            for node in adjNodes:
                
                for closedNode in closedList:
                    if(node == closedNode):
                        continue

                node.g = minNode.g + 1
                node.h = ((node.xPos - self.endNode.xPos)**2) + ((node.yPos - self.endNode.yPos)**2)
                node.f = node.h + node.g

                for openNode in openList:
                    if((node == openNode) and (node.g > openNode.g)):
                        continue
                
                openList.append(node)



class Driver:
    size = int(input("Enter the size of the graph: "))
    startX = int(input("Enter the x value of the start node: "))
    startY = int(input("Enter the y value of the start node: "))
    endX = int(input("Enter the x value of the end node: "))
    endY = int(input("Enter the y value of the end node: "))

    graph = Graph(size,startX,startY,endX,endY)
    graph.displayGraph()
    graph.findShortestPath()
```

Output when looped stopped at 20 iterations

```
Enter the size of the graph: 10
Enter the x value of the start node: 2
Enter the y value of the start node: 2
Enter the x value of the end node: 9
Enter the y value of the end node: 9
(0,0,open) (0,1,open) (0,2,open) (0,3,open) (0,4,open) (0,5,open) (0,6,open) (0,7,open) (0,8,open) (0,9,open) 
(1,0,open) (1,1,open) (1,2,open) (1,3,open) (1,4,open) (1,5,open) (1,6,open) (1,7,open) (1,8,open) (1,9,open) 
(2,0,open) (2,1,open) (2,2,start) (2,3,open) (2,4,open) (2,5,open) (2,6,open) (2,7,open) (2,8,open) (2,9,open) 
(3,0,open) (3,1,open) (3,2,open) (3,3,open) (3,4,open) (3,5,open) (3,6,open) (3,7,open) (3,8,open) (3,9,open) 
(4,0,open) (4,1,open) (4,2,open) (4,3,open) (4,4,open) (4,5,open) (4,6,open) (4,7,open) (4,8,open) (4,9,open) 
(5,0,open) (5,1,open) (5,2,open) (5,3,open) (5,4,open) (5,5,open) (5,6,open) (5,7,open) (5,8,open) (5,9,open) 
(6,0,open) (6,1,open) (6,2,open) (6,3,open) (6,4,open) (6,5,open) (6,6,open) (6,7,open) (6,8,open) (6,9,open) 
(7,0,open) (7,1,open) (7,2,open) (7,3,open) (7,4,open) (7,5,open) (7,6,open) (7,7,open) (7,8,open) (7,9,open) 
(8,0,open) (8,1,open) (8,2,open) (8,3,open) (8,4,open) (8,5,open) (8,6,open) (8,7,open) (8,8,open) (8,9,open) 
(9,0,open) (9,1,open) (9,2,open) (9,3,open) (9,4,open) (9,5,open) (9,6,open) (9,7,open) (9,8,open) (9,9,end) 

(2,3,open)
(3,3,open)
(3,2,open)
(3,1,open)
(2,1,open)
(1,1,open)
(1,2,open)
(1,3,open)

(1,2,open)
(2,2,start)
(2,1,open)
(2,0,open)
(1,0,open)
(0,0,open)
(0,1,open)
(0,2,open)

(0,1,open)
(1,1,open)
(1,0,open)

(1,1,open)
(2,1,open)
(2,0,open)
(0,0,open)
(0,1,open)

(0,1,open)
(1,1,open)
(1,0,open)

(0,2,open)
(1,2,open)
(1,1,open)
(1,0,open)
(0,0,open)

(0,1,open)
(1,1,open)
(1,0,open)

(0,2,open)
(1,2,open)
(1,1,open)
(1,0,open)
(0,0,open)

(0,1,open)
(1,1,open)
(1,0,open)

(1,1,open)
(2,1,open)
(2,0,open)
(0,0,open)
(0,1,open)

(0,1,open)
(1,1,open)
(1,0,open)

(0,2,open)
(1,2,open)
(1,1,open)
(1,0,open)
(0,0,open)

(0,1,open)
(1,1,open)
(1,0,open)

(0,2,open)
(1,2,open)
(1,1,open)
(1,0,open)
(0,0,open)

(0,1,open)
(1,1,open)
(1,0,open)

(1,1,open)
(2,1,open)
(2,0,open)
(0,0,open)
(0,1,open)

(0,1,open)
(1,1,open)
(1,0,open)

(1,1,open)
(2,1,open)
(2,0,open)
(0,0,open)
(0,1,open)

(0,1,open)
(1,1,open)
(1,0,open)

(0,2,open)
(1,2,open)
(1,1,open)
(1,0,open)
(0,0,open)
```

Comment: To me, it looks like your conditional/continue statements aren't working as intended. This results in a selection bias in the direction that occurs first in getAdj(), which is toward the origin.

Comment: @Ghoti theoretically wouldn't the order not matter if the heuristics are calculated correctly? Because whichever node has the lowest total cost is selected for the path. Perhaps I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: The calculation order of adjNodes() doesn't matter. I'm suggesting that your method of selecting the lowest cost node has a flaw that makes it so that the first node is always selected.

Comment: @Ghoti I see the mistake now. It was a simple comparison that was incorrect. `minNode.f < openList[i].f` The inequality should be the other way around. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by user @Ghoti the issue was a simple comparison error in the algorithm. With the current comparison statement in the code above the first node in the adjNode list is always selected.

```
if(minNode.f < openList[i].f):
    minNode = openList[i]
    minIndex = i
```

Instead, it is as simple as flipping the inequality to compare the other way. A simple elementary algebra mistake. The correct comparison would be: `minNode.f > openList[i].f`